# Printing numerous specific lines from file using awk or sed command loop

Tags: bash, awk

I've got this big txt file with ID names. It has 2500 lines, one column. Let's call it file.txt

```
H3430
H3467
H9805
```

Also, I've got another file, index.txt, which has 390 numbers:

```
1
4
9
13
15
```

Those numbers are the number of lines (of IDs) I have to extract from file.txt. I need to generate another file, newfile.txt let's call it, with only the 390 IDs that are in the specific lines that index.txt demands (the first ID of the list, the fourth, the ninth, and so on).

So, I tried to do the following loop, but it didn't work.

```
num=$'index.txt'
for i in num
do
awk 'NR==i' "file.txt" > newfile.txt
done
```

I'm a noob regarding this matters... so, I need some help. Even if it is with my loop or with a new solution suggested by you. Thank you :)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!  It looks like you are asking for homework help.  While we have no issues with that per se, please observe these [dos and don'ts](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334822/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions/338845#338845), and edit your question accordingly.

Comment: It isn't homework help. I'm a biologist trying to further my learning in these topics, because I want to. I generated those files from an analysis I'm performing, but sometimes I get stuck because I'm not from a computer science area. If it seems like 'homework' is because im a didactic person (I teach), and I tried to be clear.
But I understand what you're saying. Thank you anyway

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Lets create an example file that simulates your 2500 line file with `seq`:

```
$ seq 2500 > /tmp/2500
```

And use the example you have for the line numbers to print in a file called 390:

```
$ echo "1
4
9
13
15" > /tmp/390
```

You can print line N in the file 2500 by reading the line numbers into an array and printing the lines if in that array:

```
$ awk 'NR==FNR{ a[$1]++; next} a[FNR]' /tmp/390 /tmp/2500
```

You can also use a `sed` command file:

```
$ sed 's/$/p/' /tmp/390 > /tmp/sed_cmd
$ sed -n -f /tmp/sed_cmd /tmp/2500
```

With GNU sed, you can do `sed 's/$/p/' /tmp/390 | sed -n -f - /tmp/2500` but that does not work on OS X :-(

You can do this tho:

```
$ sed -n -f <(sed 's/$/p/' /tmp/390) /tmp/2500
```

Comment: Creating a script with `sed` to feed to `sed` is strangely beautiful (and the sign of a warped mind). Love it.

Comment: Yup, bootstrapping is cool. Unfortunately it fails when the generated script gets large though and that limit is surprisingly easy to hit when you're selecting lines from a file one command a time. I think somewhere around a thousand lines of commands is where it tanks but it may depend on the length of each command and may be different for different sed variants, idk. The awk command OTOH will work robustly, efficiently, and portably across all awks on all systems for enormous files.

Answer (score 2):

You can read the index.txt file in to a map and then compare it with the line number of file.txt. Redirect the output to another file.

```
awk 'NR==FNR{line[$1]; next}(FNR in line){print $1}' index.txt file.txt > newfile.txt
```

When you work with two files, using FNR is necessary as it gets reset to 1 when new file starts (on the contrary NR will continue to increment).

As Ed Morton suggests in the comments. The command could then be refined to further remove `{print $1}` since awk prints by default on truth.

```
awk 'NR==FNR{line[$1]; next} FNR in line' index.txt file.txt > newfile.txt
```

Comment: It worked !!! thank you so much! But remember that i'm somewhat new.... what's FNR and what do you mean by read in to a map? If you could explain a bit, would be great. I want to understand it :)

Comment: @MelNuesch Arrays in awk are associative in nature. The indices are strings. They are also known as dictionary in Python or HashMap in Java. FNR is a built-in awk variable that remembers line number of the current file. I would recommend grabbing [this book](https://www.amazon.com/Effective-awk-Programming-Universal-Processing/dp/1491904615/ref=dp_ob_title_bk) which will explain awk in much more detail.

Answer (score 0):

If `index.txt` is sorted, we could walk `file.txt` in order.
That reduces the number of actions to the very minimum (faster script):

```
awk 'BEGIN
     {  indexfile="index.txt"
        if ( (getline ind < indexfile) <= 0)
             { printf("Empty %s\n; exiting",indexfile);exit }
     }
     {  if ( FNR <  ind ) next
        if ( FNR == ind ) printf("%s %s\n",ind,$0)
        if ( (getline ind < indexfile) <= 0) {exit}
     }' file.txt
```

If the file is not actually sorted, get it quickly sorted with sort:

```
sort -n index.txt > temp.index.txt
rm index.txt
mv temp.index.txt index.txt
```